# list of strings to list of tuples of string

Tags: python, string, list, tuples

I have a list of strings of the sort

```
['aaa','bbb','ccc']
```

I need to convert them into a list of tuples like this,

```
[('aaa',),('bbb',),('ccc',)]
```

When I try to apply the tuple function to each element of the list, it splits the string and returns something of the sort

```
('a','a','a')
```

Is there a way to work around this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), and tuple creation via the 'single item tuple creation method' or look [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue2817) for information about this.

```
lst = ['aaa','bbb','ccc']
tpl_lst = [(i,) for i in lst]
```

Yields:

```
[('aaa',), ('bbb',), ('ccc',)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't apply tuple function, since it takes the string as sequence, and breaks it's characters apart. You can simply build `tuple` manually with [List Comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)like this:

```
>>> l = ['aaa','bbb','ccc']
>>> [(elem,) for elem in l]
[('aaa',), ('bbb',), ('ccc',)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> l = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
>>> print [(i,) for i in l]
[('aaa',), ('bbb',), ('ccc',)]
```

All you need to do is put each element in its own one-tuple.